# How to resolve "bitcode bundle could not be generated because 'AFNetworking framework/paytabs-iOS(UIColor+Helpers.o)' was built without full bitcode"

Tags: ios, swift, paytabs

I have implemented paytab payment gateway
these are the steps which i have follow from the documentation of the paytab
[in this link](https://dev.paytabs.com/docs/ios/).

steps which i did

1. download the sdk from the above link
2. add to my project
3. add the import line to the header file

   ```
   #import <paytabs-iOS/paytabs_iOS.h>
   ```
4. install the following pods to my project for the paytab as documentation said

   #for PayTabs

   ```
   pod 'BIObjCHelpers'
   pod 'Mantle'
   pod 'Lockbox'
   pod 'SBJson'
   pod 'PINCache'
   pod 'PayCardsRecognizer'
   pod 'Reachability'
   pod 'AFNetworking'
   pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.1.0'
   pod 'ActionSheetPicker'
   ```

This is working file when i am installing on iPhone with wire. The error is coming when i am generating the ipa (Archive) in pod "AFNetworking". Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable bitcode or wait for that framework to support full bitcode.

To disable bitcode, select your project -> Build Settings -> search for `Enable Bitcode` and set to `No`
[image]

Comment: yes but when i am setting Enable Bitcode to NO then this is not generating IPA (Archieve) file.